# Error: createEncodedCachedResponseAndRequestForXPCTransmission . Executing app in iOS 8.0

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am getting below error when I try to execute my code in iOS 8.0

```
    ERROR: createEncodedCachedResponseAndRequestForXPCTransmission - Invalid protocol-property list - CFURLRequestRef. protoProps=<CFBasicHash 0xf416930 [0x3b69510]>{type = mutable dict, count = 1,
entries =>
    1 : <CFString 0x5e9758 [0x3b69510]>{contents = "NR_PROTOCOL_DELEGATE_TRACKER"} = <SRStudiesRequest: 0xf1890a0>
}
```

I googled with "createEncodedCachedResponseAndRequestForXPCTransmission" keyword but nothing of much help. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

For me, this ERROR was the result of utilizing NSURLProtocol and the "setProperty" method.

[NSURLProtocol setProperty:FOO forKey:BAR inRequest:newRequest];

I am not exactly certain of what is going on here, but from my experience I had two NSURLProtocol implementations.  One needed property (FOO) and the other didn't.

Core Code sets (FOO)
NSURLProtocol #1 gets (FOO) and handles the COMM itself
--- no issue

NSURLProtocol #2 doesn't access (FOO) and hands of the COMM to a SESSION 
-- shows the error above

Commenting out the Core Code that sets the (FOO) property solves the problem for NSURLProtocol #2.  Obviously if you are using 3rd-party code, this would be more difficult to manage.

BTW, in my case this "ERROR" didn't break the follow of logic and operated more as a warning.